# How to show the column names of a table?

Tags: mysql

The case is simple: You have a MySQL database where you have only an SQL query interface and you want to know the database structure with queries. You can list tables with `show tables;` command, but how do you see the individual column names?

*(`SELECT` statement shows `Empty set` if no data is present and can NOT be thus used.)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best solution that I found out by myself was the `desc table_name` command. More information is on *[List MySQL Tables](http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/mysql/listing-tables.php)*. This command gives the description of one database table, which is exactly what I was trying to find out.

Answer (score 37):

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='table'
```

Answer (score 6):

To make sure you list columns in a table in the current database, [use the DATABASE() or SCHEMA() function](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0400__Information-Functions/SCHEMAisasynonymforDATABASE.htm). It returns NULL if you are not in a current database. This query will show the columns in a table in the order the columns were defined:

```
SELECT column_name,column_type
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = DATABASE()
AND table_name='table'
ORDER BY ordinal_position;
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean with table *titles*, but you can get most of the information about tables and their columns from the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-schema.html)

Answer (score 3):

> how do you see the individual table titles?

Do you mean [table comments](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html)?

```
use stack;
create table t(v integer primary key) comment 'My Special Table';

show tables;
+-----------------+
| Tables_in_stack |
+-----------------+
| t               |
+-----------------+

select table_name, table_comment from information_schema.tables where table_name='t';
+------------+------------------+
| table_name | table_comment    |
+------------+------------------+
| t          | My Special Table |
+------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM mydb.mytable;
```

where 
mydb - is the database that contains needed table

mytable - is the needed table

It return info of columns (for examp. names of columns, type, e t c)

Answer (score 0):

You need to join `information_schema.tables` and `information_schema.columns` together to get the list of tables and their columns' details.

`information_schema.columns` not only shows detail about tables but also views. There is no way to filter only table details from this system view.

Hence you need to join.

Example query:

```
select t.TABLE_SCHEMA, t.TABLE_NAME, c.COLUMN_NAME, c.COLUMN_TYPE, c.DATA_TYPE
from information_schema.tables t , information_schema.columns c where 2=2 
and t.table_schema=c.table_schema
and t.table_name=c.table_name
and t.table_type ='BASE TABLE' 
order by t.table_schema, t.table_name, c.column_name 
;
```